# How with predis on laravel save data with long key?

Tags: laravel, redis, predis

Using redis on laravel site I need to save some collections of data, based on provided filter.
I use formatted string with filtered value as key.
Such key :

```
filterPublished=1;filterTitle=a;sortByField=published;sortOrdering=desc;additiveSortByField=title;additiveSortOrdering=asc
```

is invalid

This key is valid:

```
fP=1;fT=a;sF=published;sO=desc;aSBF=title;aSO=asc
```

and collection of data with such key is successfully saved.

Actually

```
fT=filterTitle
```

I suppose that first key does not work as is it rather long(122 chars)
But second key also can be invalid if key "fT" would have some long text.
That is custom filter utility where user enters some values when searching for data.

1. Which is max length of such key? Is it restriction of redis or predis library ?
2. Are there better decisions/tools for such cases?

   "laravel/framework": "^9.48.0",
   "predis/predis": "^2.1",

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The suggested way to use redis in laravel is with the extension [phpredis](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis). Redis itself has a key limit of 512MB but does not recommend using keys longer than 1kb. Your keys are nowhere near those limits so I don't think your issue has to do with key limits. I have tested 5kb keys in Laravel using redis (with phpredis though) and it has no problems at all

Comment: Thanks! I will try phpredis. Please point to links where these limits are described.
Also which characters can not be used in key ? I suppose ":", as it is used in key/subkey separator? 
Some more ?

Comment: There's no restriction in keys imposed by Redis. According to [this](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/tutorial/) they are binary safe, there are recommendations on how you could structure them though

Comment: After some tests I found that rather long keys(more 130 chars) are written into redis, but are not visible in phpRedisAdmin.
Entering into redis cli I see my priorly entered keys:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *  
1) "_votes_db_filterPublished=1;filterTitle=a;sortByField=published;sortOrdering=desc;additiveSortByField=title;additiveSortOrdering=asc"
2) "_votes_db_filterPublished=1;filterTitle=Test article;sortByField=published;sortOrdering=desc;additiveSortByField"
...
```
Are thee some suitable redis client for kubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: Maybe check out one of the tools mentioned [here](https://redis.com/blog/so-youre-looking-for-the-redis-gui/)